# How do I get all records where date is 6 months greater than today's date, using Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a date field of lastDelivery, and I want to retrieve all records that are 6 months or more older than today's date, how do I do this?

Comment: `where lastDelivery > dateadd(month, 6, getdate())`

Comment: Edited my question - this didn't work, I meant 6 months or more older than today's date.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE lastdelivery <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

**Query**

```
select * from your_table_name
where lastDelivery <= dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            DECLARE @subscriptions TABLE
            (
                OrderId int,
                OrderName varchar(255),
                lastDelivery date default getdate()
            )

            INSERT INTO @subscriptions (OrderName, lastDelivery) 
            VALUES 
            ( 'Allen', '2015-05-20'),
            ( 'Bob', '2015-06-20'),
            ( 'Craig', '2015-07-20'),
            ( 'David', '2015-08-20'),
            ( 'Edward', '2015-09-20'),
            ( 'Frank', '2015-10-20'),
            ( 'George', '2015-11-20'),
            ( 'Harry', '2015-12-20')

            SELECT OrderName FROM @subscriptions
            WHERE lastDelivery <= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried some of the above, they do not work for me but this works:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_Columns` WHERE `date` <= '2020-01-13 04:40:51'
```

Please note that my date is manually set to 6 months ago.